# Ambiguous occurrence ‘empty’ even with a " as Prefix "

Tags: haskell, ambiguous

I was trying to implement a two stacks queue in Haskell but at the very first of my code I get this error.

```
TwoStacksQueue.hs:3:5:
    Ambiguous occurrence ‘empty’
    It could refer to either ‘DataStructures.Queue.TwoStacksQueue.empty’,
                      defined at TwoStacksQueue.hs:15:1
                      or ‘LS.empty’,
                      imported from ‘DataStructures.Stack.LinearStack’
```

This is the code (I cant even start with isEmpty):

```
module DataStructures.Queue.TwoStacksQueue
( Queue
, empty
, isEmpty
, enqueue
, dequeue
, first
) where

import DataStructures.Stack.LinearStack as LS

data Queue a = Empty | Node a (Stack a) (Stack a)

empty :: Queue a
empty = Empty
```

Comment: Look at the line number - the error is in your exports list. You export `empty` but there are two such names in scope. You probably want `import qualified DataStructures.Stack...`

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a module `A`:

```
module A (Foo, Bar) where
data Foo = …
data Bar = …
```

When you write:

```
import A as B
```

That brings `B.Foo`, and `B.Bar` into scope, but it *also* brings in the unqualified `Foo` and `Bar`. When you use a `qualified` import, *only* the qualified names (`B.Foo`, `B.Bar`) are imported. For example:

```
import qualified DataStructures.Stack.LinearStack as LS
       ---------
```

With this, `empty` in your export list will refer unambiguously to `DataStructures.Queue.TwoStacksQueue.empty`, but you have to qualify all functions from `DataStructures.Stack.LinearStack` with the `LS.` prefix, unless you import them explicitly:

```
import DataStructures.Stack.LinearStack (foo, bar)
```

Alternatively, in the export list, you can fully qualify the name of the function in the current module:

```
module DataStructures.Queue.TwoStacksQueue
  ( DataStructures.Queue.TwoStacksQueue.empty
  , …
  ) where
```

Generally speaking, `import qualified … as …` is a sane default. It generates some prefix clutter in the code, but it prevents name collisions like this. It’s also more future-proof: using *unqualified* imports, if `DataStructures.Stack.LinearStack` exports a new function, then you may have to change any module that imports it, if there is a name collision.